# How to combine/merge mostly identical sublists into one, and append the non-identical part to the end of the list?

Tags: python, list, sublist

How do you combine/merge identical sublists into one sublist, and append the non-identical part at the end of the list?

For example, the only differentiating factor within these sublists are week numbers and the counts at the end of each sublist. I'd like to have only one sublist for each unique 'UserId','Amount', and 'Email' and append the non-identical part to this one sublist.

To complicate things further, I'd like the order of the 'counts' to be in the order by which week they fall under. For example, below you can see 1 for week 1, 10 for week 2, 14 for week 4, and nothing for week 3. In the case that there is no value, append a 0 instead.

```
lst = [
        [
          ['UserID','Amount','Email','week1',1],
          ['UserID','Amount','Email','week4',14],
          ['UserID','Amount','Email','week2',10]

        ],
        [
          ['UserID2','Amount','Email','week1',99],
          ['UserID2','Amount','Email','week2',10],
          ['UserID2','Amount','Email','week4',14]
        ]
      ]

Desired_List = [
                 ['UserID','Amount','Email','week1',1,10,0,14],
                 ['UserID2','Amount','Email','week1',99,10,0,14]
               ]
```

This would combine them to produce the result, but it does not place a 0 for missing weeks:

```
[grp[0][:-1]+[item[-1] for item in grp] for grp in lst]
```

Comment: `[os.path.commonprefix(el) for el in lst]` and you do the rest.

Comment: Where do the `0`s in the `Desired_List` come from?

Comment: It's not about path names. It's about reusing the code because the purpose is the same

Comment: Answers to your previous questions have covered many of Python's tools for dealing with problems like these.  Did every single attempt fail?

Comment: Thanks! The 0s come from the fact that there is no sublist for week3, so I wanted a 0 to represent week3. Otherwise, the issue is that ['UserID','Amount','Email','week1',1,10,14] looks like it was 1 on week 1, 10, on week 2, and 14 on week 3, when it was actually 0 on week 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve may not be suitable for a one liner. My approach as outlined below, considers the variable part which is the last two items in the list as a key - value in a dictionary.

Now, with the dictionary in place, create a sequence of week numbers. This can easily be done using `str.format` and determining the maximum week for any given sub-list `int(max(seq[0][-1])[4:])`.

Finally, using `dict.get`, lookup the dictionary and for any missing key, default it to `0`

**Implementation**

```
def foo(seq):
    from operator import itemgetter
    # | [['UserID', 'Amount', 'Email', {'week1': 1, 'week2': 10, 'week4': 14}], .|
    # V                                                                          V
    seq_dict = (grp[0][:3] + [dict(map(itemgetter(3,4), grp))] for grp in lst)
    # 'week4' | '4' | 4
    max_weeks = int(max(seq[0][-1])[4:])
    # | ['week1', 'week2', 'week3', 'week4'] |
    # V                                      V
    week_range = range(1, max_weeks + 1)
    return [items[:-1] + [items[-1].get("week{}".format(week), 0) 
                          for week in week_range]
            for items in seq_dict]
```

**Output**

```
>>> pprint.pprint(foo(lst))
[['UserID', 'Amount', 'Email', 1, 10, 0, 14],
 ['UserID2', 'Amount', 'Email', 99, 10, 0, 14]]
```

Comment: The only caveat here is that lst has to be in the right order, which isn't always guaranteed. For example, this doesn't work for when week4 precedes week2 in lst

Comment: @Chris: If they are any particular order, where should the missing week value be inserted? And I do not understand when you say `it doesn't work`, it actually works, except that the final output is sorted by week#

Comment: Your completely right, it does work, but output is a bit different when the weeks in the original list are sorted differently. For example, I just edited the lst above by moving week3 before week2. The result is  [['UserID', 'Amount', 'Email', 1, 10], ['UserID2', 'Amount', 'Email', 99, 10]] instead of [['UserID', 'Amount', 'Email', 1, 10, 0, 14],
 ['UserID2', 'Amount', 'Email', 99, 10, 0, 14]]

Comment: @Chris: So based on your desired output, this answer matches.

Comment: Yep, Your completely right! I'll find another way to get around this.